# yii2 datepicker show start date greater than current date

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to show dates which are greater than current date
in ValidFrom and dates greater than ValidFrom  in ValidUpto field but unable to show.I want hide previous dates in date picker.

My code is below.

```
 echo DatePicker::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'ValidFrom',
        'attribute2' => 'ValidUpto',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'valid from',

        ],
        'options2' => ['placeholder' => 'valid to'],
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
        'form' => $form,

        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'autoclose' => true,
        ],

    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a id attribute to the date picker:

```
        echo DatePicker::widget([
        'id'=>'mydatepicker',
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'ValidFrom',
        'attribute2' => 'ValidUpto',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'valid from',

        ],
        'options2' => ['placeholder' => 'valid to'],
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
        'form' => $form,

        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'autoclose' => true,
        ],

    ]);
```

Set minDate to the date picker in your view file:

```
    <?
    $script = <<< JS
    $( "#mydatepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd", minDate: 0});
    JS;
    $this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
    ?>
```